# Why does this code crash after Arduino reset?

Tags: c++, class, oop, arduino, crash

I'm attempting to make an object-oriented robotic arm with an Arduino. I'm trying to control the stepper motors through the class Joint. I already had some problems making the sketch compile and execute because I'm pretty new to C++ and I don't really know a lot about classes, pointers, etc. Eventually, I found that this code works:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

class Joint {
  private:
    int NextStep;

  public:
    Stepper *TestStepper;
    *Joint(int StepsPerRevolution, int DirPin, int StepPin) {
      TestStepper = new Stepper(StepsPerRevolution, DirPin, StepPin);
    }
};

Joint a(200, 3, 4);

void setup() { 
}

void loop() {
  a.TestStepper->step(1);
  delay(2);
}
```

It works fine. The only problem is that when I reset (from the onboard button) the Arduino, it crashes and I can't get it to start again not even by unplugging and plugging it back. To make it work I have to first unplug it, upload new code (down here) a few times until I can get it back to work and then upload the code with the class.

```
#include <Stepper.h>
Stepper stepper(200, 3, 4);

void setup(){
}

void loop() {
  stepper.step(1);
  delay(2);
}
```

I think I've figured out it has something to do with the class because the other code works perfectly even after multiples reset. Also when I reset a "crashed" Arduino, it does a small step as if it gets blocked after one iteration of loop()

I'm using an Arduino Due and an A4988 Stepper Driver. I'm programming the Arduino through the Native USB and powering the motor with a 9v battery.

Comment: What asterisk in `*Joint(int StepsPerRevolution, int DirPin, int StepPin)` is supposed to mean?

Comment: I think the error is because your class instance is global. Read: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45794.0

Comment: I guessed I put it there for some reason and forgot to remove it. Sorry, I'm really new to cpp. Also removing it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I gave the post a look, but I don't think I understood what I have to do completely. Do I have to add a begin() method? What does it need to do?

Comment: You could do that, or you could move the instance inside a specific scope. (Such as that of a function). Keep in mind, I'm not _entirely_ sure that is the problem.

Comment: I don't think that could be the problem because the program only crashes after the Arduino reset

Comment: just a thought, maybe try resetting the arduino from code instead of from the onboard button http://www.instructables.com/id/two-ways-to-reset-arduino-in-software/